# Android: App crashes when initializing new AsyncTask (VerifyError)

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have an an app that crashes at the Point: "new Downloader(this, mURL);":

```
    Downloader downloader = new Downloader(this, mURL);
    downloader.execute(0);
```

Downloader.java:

```
public class Downloader extends AsyncTask<Integer,Integer,String>{

private Fragment fragment;
private String mURL;
private Activity activity;

public Downloader(VertretungsplanFragment fr, String mURL)
{
    fragment = fr;
    this.mURL = mURL;
    this.activity = fr.getActivity();
}
@Override
protected String doInBackground(Integer... integers) {
[...]}
}
```

Then this Error appears (important: it only crashes on Android < 3)

> java.lang.VerifyError

Here's the Error Log :)

--startDownload:253 is exactly Downloader downlaoder = new Downlaoder(this, mURL);

> 02-25 15:40:55.405      619-619/thems.vertretungsplan E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       java.lang.VerifyError: thems.vertretungsplan.Downloader
>               at thems.vertretungsplan.VertretungsplanFragment.startDownload(VertretungsplanFragment.java:253)
>               at thems.vertretungsplan.VertretungsplanFragment.onCreateView(VertretungsplanFragment.java:58)
>               at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1500)
>               at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:927)
>               at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
>               at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
>               at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1467)
>               at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:472)
>               at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141)
>               at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1068)
>               at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:914)
>               at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1436)
>               at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
>               at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
>               at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1017)
>               at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:386)
>               at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:309)
>               at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
>               at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
>               at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
>               at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
>               at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:581)
>               at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:365)
>               at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
>               at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
>               at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
>               at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
>               at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
>               at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
>               at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
>               at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure(DrawerLayout.java:651)
>               at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
>               at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
>               at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
>               at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
>               at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:531)
>               at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:309)
>               at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
>               at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
>               at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
>               at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
>               at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
>               at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
>               at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
>               at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:839)
>               at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1859)
>               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
>               at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: can you post your error log?

Answer (score 0):

You have to get the context from the Activity that instanced the fragment.

```
context =new Context();
context = getActivity();
```

Pass this "context" as context to the asynctask constructor.

Comment: I actually don't understand. - Why do I need a context in Async-Task

Comment: When you call  Downloader downloader = new Downloader(this, mURL); You have to put the context of the activity your fragment is currently associated with.So you put the code i wrote in my answer in your fragment and instead of "this",you put "context in your constructor.i.e. Downloader downloader = new Downloader(context, mURL);

Comment: First of all - thanks for help, but this is not the problem of the crash - it actually doesn't get into public Downloader(...). Any idea? - The crazy thing about is that it works with android 3+

Answer (score 0):

Fragments were introduced after android 3.0 i.e API level 11

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html

Comment: Well, this is actually not the problem either... By commenting the two lines with "Downloader" it works as it should... Btw: I use AndroidStudio - could that be a problem?